# Unmount partition mounted at /home and move /home to partition mounted at /

Tags: linux, debian, mount, debian-installer, lsblk

I have two partitions on my Debian machine. One(first) is mounted at root `/` and the other(second) is mounted at `/home`(There are two users `root` and `ako` in `/home/` directory).

Now, I want to unmount first partition and put `/home` under second one(partition mounted at `/`), so that I can install `Windows-10` on second one.

How can I do that without corrupting my Debian OS?

Here is output of `lsblk`:

[image: lsblk]

`sdb` device is what I'm taking about.

Comment: Could you please clarify? I've confused. You want to move `home` under `/` and move new `/` that contain in `sdc1`?

Comment: Please add the output of `df -h` to the question. Please avoid images where test will do. Tagalog?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually very simple.

1. Make sure, using `df` and following the old adage to *measure seven times before you cut*, that there is enough room on partition #1 for all of the contents of partition #5.
2. Unmount partition #5 from `/home` as you have done.
3. Make a directory such `/home.old`.
4. Remount partition #5 at `/home.old`.  For best results, mount it read-only.
5. Use a command to recursively copy everything from `/home.old` to `/home`.
6. `sync`
7. *Check* that everything has been successfully copied. Check *everything*.
8. Check that you haven't exceeded the maximum size on partition #1.  Remember that you did this as the superuser, and so were allowed to eat into the superuser's emergency free space on the volume.
9. Unmount `/home.old`.

Step #5 is the one with all of the pitfalls.  You *must* use a command that preserves all permissions, ACLs, and ownerships; and that does not break multiply-linked files into multiple singly-linked files.  `pax -r -w -pe` and `rsync -H -A -a` are some of the several ways of doing this, which are beyond the scope of this answer.  There are plenty of answers *already here long since* dealing in how to copy directory trees preserving everything.

Whether Windows 10 will fit into 55GiB in your normal use is also beyond the scope of this answer. ☺

Having the superuser's home directory on a non-root volume was not a good idea, as sometimes one wants the superuser to have a home directory even if one is bootstrapped into emergency mode.  Having ordinary users' home directories on a separate volume probably was, though.  On the gripping hand, it should be obvious how to reverse this procedure when the time comes.

## Further reading

- [Copying files while maintaining file attributes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325318/)
- [What optimized tools are available for comparing directory contents?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208211/)
- https://superuser.com/questions/987608/

Comment: I actually liked the comment about "Whether Windows 10 will fit into 55GiB in your normal use is also beyond the scope of this answer. " +1 ;-P I prefer using `tar` for moving dirs.