# Merge /home partition to partition mounted at /

Tags: ubuntu, partition, rsync, docker, move-partition

My current situation is the one shown below:
[image: Partition Table of my 256GB drive]

What I want to do is to remove /home partition and have it as a directory in the  file system mounted at /

I consulted [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428594/unmount-partition-mounted-at-home-and-move-home-to-partition-mounted-at) in order to do so but in my case there is not enough space in the / partition to just copy all the contents of /home so I figured I'd try the following steps:

1. Transfer all the contents of ~ to a temporary partition.
2. Delete partition mounted at /home.
3. Grow partition mounted at /
4. Move everything from the temporary volume to my home directory.

I used `sudo rsync -H -A -a --progress ~ /media/mark/tmp/` in order to copy everything from my home directory into the temporary partition which happens to be a 64GB usb stick but even though both gparted(as shown above) and `du -sh ~` show the used space of the partition mounted at /home as way less than 64GB,

[image: partition mounted at /home used space]

The output of `rsync` is the one bellow:
[image: rsync output]

That basically states that my temporary medium has run out of available space.

Is there anything that I'm doing that is completely out of bound?
Could it be a docker issue?

Any feedback would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Asking the obvious: was the 64GB stick empty? =}

Comment: Yes, using the Disks gui program that is shipped with gnome in ubuntu. Newly partitioned with ext4 which I think caused it to create a lost+found folder of 20K in size.

Comment: you may have sparse files.  I use these rsync options: `-aAHSxPhW --sparse --force --fuzzy --delete`.  Of course you need to be careful.  If you have sparse files, just look at the biggest files on usb stick and in your homedirectory,  and run stat on them, to see if there is a blocks mismatch.  Either way, you will have to delete those files off the usb, and then rsync again with the sparse option.

Comment: Try `du -csh --apparent-size` for /home/mark and usb stick. You may have fake usb stick with far less real capacity then reported size.

Comment: With gparted live cd you can shrink and move beginning of home partition/fs, grow root partition/fs, copy data to root fs, delete home partition after and grow root partition/fs finally

Comment: @toppk Thank you very much, I hadn't thought of sparse files, I'll try and replicate my problem as I resulted in the live usb option.

Comment: @gapsf I ended up going that route, thank you very much and yes gparted from live usb worked like a charm!